# Chromebook - Sort and Filter in Google Sheets while Offline

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, chromebook

I have spreadsheets stored offline on a Chromebook that I would like to sort and filter without needing to go online.

They were created by downloading from Google Sheets, but when I open them locally the Sort/Filter functionality is not available. I have tried saving them with several file extensions, but I have not found one that works. (Although I may be missing something.)

Is there anything I can do to get the Sort/Filter function while offline?

For security reasons I would prefer not to download a new program to handle the spreadsheets while offline, although I realise this may be the only solution.